# Optimize query with match against in 3 tables. Mysql

Tags: mysql, match, full-text-search

I am trying to optimize this query since it takes me 3.7 seconds. I have also been reviewing the EXPLAIN and I can see the number of rows that it traverses which is important. But beyond that I would not know how to optimize it. Although I know that the amount of data that goes through is "large", the Query should not have this delay. I used to do this query with like so you can imagine how long it was and how long it took.

I would appreciate any suggestions. Thanks

```
SELECT
  e.identificacion,g.serie,g.terminal,
  g.serie_base,g.tarjeta,g.accesorio_uno,g.accesorio_dos,
  g.accesorio_tres,g.accesorio_cuatro,e.emailcliente,
  e.empresa, e.localidad,e.provincia,e.direccion,
  e.codigo_postal,e.estado,u.name
FROM equipos e 
INNER JOIN gestion g ON g.id_equipo = e.id
INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = g.id_user
WHERE g.created_at >= '2021-04-01'
  AND g.created_at <= '2021-04-27%'
  AND g.status_gestion = 'transito'
  and ( 
    MATCH (e.identificacion,e.emailcliente,
           e.empresa,e.localidad,e.provincia,
           e.direccion,e.codigo_postal,e.estado,
           e.created_at) 
    AGAINST ('"*MARIANOD302@GMAIL.COM*"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    OR 
    MATCH (g.identificacion,g.terminal,g.serie,
           g.serie_base,g.tarjeta,g.estado,g.created_at) 
    AGAINST ('"*correoGMAIL.COM*"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    OR 
    MATCH (u.name) AGAINST ('"*correo@GMAIL.COM*"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
  )
```

My tables are INNODB:

- equipos have 240,000 rows
- gestion 45,000 rows
- users 700 rows

[explain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6f1P.png)

Table structure with their indexes

equipos

```
CREATE TABLE `equipos` (
    `id` INT(15) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `id_local` INT(15) NOT NULL,
    `cod_empresa` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `tipo` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `empresa` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `equipo` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `tarjeta` VARCHAR(80) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `terminal` VARCHAR(80) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `serie` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `temp` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `serie_base` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `idd` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `id_orden` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `id_actividad` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `identificacion` VARCHAR(60) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `nombre_cliente` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `direccion` VARCHAR(250) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `localidad` VARCHAR(150) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `codigo_postal` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `provincia` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `fecha_creacion` VARCHAR(30) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `telefono1` VARCHAR(80) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `telefono2` VARCHAR(80) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `telefono_fijo1` VARCHAR(80) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `telefono_fijo2` VARCHAR(80) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `telefono_fijo3` VARCHAR(80) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `telefono_cel4` VARCHAR(80) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `telefono_cel5` VARCHAR(80) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `telefono_cel6` VARCHAR(80) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `fecha_de_envio` VARCHAR(60) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `cartera` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `baja` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `emailcliente` VARCHAR(150) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `id_user` VARCHAR(150) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `otrosaccesorios` VARCHAR(150) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `id_orden_pass` VARCHAR(150) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `order_rec` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `latitude` VARCHAR(150) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `longitude` VARCHAR(150) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `fecha_ingreso` VARCHAR(150) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `fecha_add` VARCHAR(150) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `fechafirma` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `motivo_retiro` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `doc_entrega` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `aclaracion_entrega` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `momento` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `estado` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `created_at` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `updated_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
    `search` TEXT(65535) DEFAULT NULL AS (concat(`identificacion`,' ',`emailcliente`,' ',`empresa`,' ',`localidad`,' ',`provincia`,' ',`direccion`,' ',`codigo_postal`,' ',`estado`,' ',`created_at`)) virtual COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
    UNIQUE INDEX `id_local` (`id_local`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `identificacion` (`identificacion`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `tarjeta` (`tarjeta`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `empresa` (`empresa`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `provincia` (`provincia`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `codigo_postal` (`codigo_postal`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `localidad` (`localidad`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `id_orden_pass` (`id_orden_pass`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `serie` (`terminal`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `terminal` (`serie`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `id_user` (`id_user`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `horario_rec` (`created_at`) USING BTREE,
    FULLTEXT INDEX `INDEXEQUIPOS` (`identificacion`, `emailcliente`, `empresa`, `localidad`, `provincia`, `direccion`, `codigo_postal`, `estado`, `created_at`)
)
```

gestion

```
CREATE TABLE `gestion` (
        `id` INT(50) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `id_equipo` INT(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
        `id_orden_pass` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
        `id_orden` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
        `id_user` INT(20) NOT NULL,
        `id_user_update` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
        `identificacion` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
        `terminal` VARCHAR(80) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
        `serie` VARCHAR(70) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
        `serie_base` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
        `tarjeta` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
        `chip_alternativo` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
        `accesorio_uno` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
        `accesorio_dos` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
        `accesorio_tres` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
        `accesorio_cuatro` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
        `motivo` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
        `fecha_update` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
        `accesorios` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
        `estado` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
        `lat` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
        `lng` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
        `nombre_recolector` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
        `modelo` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
        `created_at` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
        `updated_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
        `status_gestion` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
        `search` TEXT(65535) DEFAULT NULL AS (concat(`identificacion`,' ',`serie`,' ',`terminal`,' ',`tarjeta`,' ',`estado`,' ',`created_at`)) virtual COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
        INDEX `estado` (`estado`) USING BTREE,
        INDEX `identificacion` (`identificacion`) USING BTREE,
        INDEX `id_local` (`id_equipo`) USING BTREE,
        INDEX `created_at` (`created_at`) USING BTREE,
        INDEX `motivo` (`motivo`) USING BTREE,
        INDEX `terminal` (`terminal`) USING BTREE,
        INDEX `serie` (`serie`) USING BTREE,
        INDEX `id_orden_pass` (`id_orden_pass`) USING BTREE,
        INDEX `id_orden` (`id_orden`) USING BTREE,
        INDEX `status_gestion` (`status_gestion`) USING BTREE,
        FULLTEXT INDEX `INDEX1` (`identificacion`, `terminal`, `serie`, `serie_base`, `tarjeta`, `estado`, `created_at`)
    )
```

users

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_managent_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `email` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `email_hash` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `password` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `password_hash` VARCHAR(200) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `name` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `surname` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `name_alternative` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `date_of_birth` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `id_number` VARCHAR(30) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `type_document` VARCHAR(15) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `id_expiration_date` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `knowledge_path` TEXT(65535) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `province` TEXT(65535) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `home_address` TEXT(65535) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `postal_code` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `country` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `location` TEXT(65535) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `phone_number` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `brand_of_vehicle` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `vehicle_type` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `vehicle_brand` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `vehicle_model` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `patent` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `year_of_vehicle` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `customer_service_hours` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `monotribute` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `cbu` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `cuit` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `bank` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `account_type` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `type_request` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `role` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `status_process` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `motive` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `description` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `status_notifications` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `status_signed` MEDIUMTEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `status_pass` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `email_verified_at` MEDIUMTEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `img_document_front` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `img_document_post` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `img_cuil_rut` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `img_monotribute` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `img_home` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `img_person` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `img_commerce` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `img_signed` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `signed_date` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `new_section` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `date_pass` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `created_at` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `updated_at` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
    `search` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL AS (concat(`email`,' ',`name`,' ',`name_alternative`,' ',`id_number`,' ',`province`,' ',`home_address`,' ',`postal_code`,' ',`country`,' ',`location`,' ',`phone_number`,' ',`cbu`,' ',`cuit`,' ',`bank`,' ',`role`,' ',`created_at`)) virtual COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
    UNIQUE INDEX `mail` (`email`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `search` (`search`) USING BTREE,
    FULLTEXT INDEX `IndexParaGestion` (`name`)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would start by doing some change to your table structure. Having all those fields is ok but match/against almost the whole table at each request will make you spend this time.

- I strongly recommend that you create an unique identifier as primary key for yours users and use only this as your reference to filter which user you wants to seek for. It can be of int type or something like a binary uuid. Remember that all tables that stores something related to an user, should have this reference as index field. I think that would be what corresponds to your field labeled as "id_user".
- Set created_at as datetime or date(depending on the format of your registers)
- Set g.status_gestion as an index, change its type to ENUM, would be much better.
- Change the order of your WHERE conditions to match first what will reject more data. It doesn't make any sense compare the date of all rows first and then filter them by user. You must filter by user first, and then compare date only for that user's rows.
  Something like: "Get only user x, filter by status_gestion(which is now an index, so is much faster) and then filter by date."

For example:

```
WHERE  
(MATCH (e.identificacion,e.emailcliente,
           e.empresa,e.localidad,e.provincia,
           e.direccion,e.codigo_postal,e.estado,
           e.created_at) 
    AGAINST ('"*MARIANOD302@GMAIL.COM*"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    OR 
    MATCH (g.identificacion,g.terminal,g.serie,
           g.serie_base,g.tarjeta,g.estado,g.created_at) 
    AGAINST ('"*correoGMAIL.COM*"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    OR 
    MATCH (u.name) AGAINST ('"*correo@GMAIL.COM*"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
) AND g.status_gestion = 'transito' AND g.created_at BETWEEN('2021-04-01','2021-04-27 23:59:59')
```

But I really think your best bet would be matching only an unique field for each user.

i.e:

```
WHERE  tableX.user_id=USER_ID
 AND g.status_gestion = 'transito' AND g.created_at BETWEEN '2021-04-01' AND '2021-04-27 23:59:59'
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. The id_user is only related in the users table. 
The id_equipo of the gestion table and the id of the equipment table are related.

Comment: @AlvaroAliaga set those main indexes as foreign key of secondary tables. It should speed up the queries.

Comment: @AlvaroAliaga if you have made those changes and noticed any performance improvement, please check the answer as correct one to help people searching solution for this kind of situation.

Answer (score 0):

The Optimizer ignores the order of things `AND'd` together in `WHERE`.  Instead, it looks at which *one* index would be best to user.  In the case of `FULLTEXT`, that will be deemed the best.  But there is still the question of which table to start with, thereby relegating the other tables to be inefficiently searched.

Some potential problems...

- `AND g.created_at <= '2021-04-27%'` makes no sense.  `%` is a wildcard for use with `LIKE`, not `<=`.
  You probably need`AND g.created_at < '2021-04-28'
- `'"*correoGMAIL.COM*"'` seems to be missing `@`.
- It is not realistic to put a date like `e.created_at` in `AGAINST...`.  Instead, parse the query and create a different query if the user is searching by date.
- If queries will make comparisons on `latitude` and `longitude`, they need to be numeric, not `VARCHAR`.

The way to optimize `OR` is to turn it into `UNION`:

```
( SELECT ... WHERE <<one of the tests>> )
UNION
( SELECT ... WHERE <<another of the tests>> )
UNION
( SELECT ... WHERE <<the other of the tests>> )
```

(There are probably more tips we can give you; make some of the changes, then come back for more advide.)